# Use NodeJs to access MySQL database to run SQL queries using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, database

Scenario:

Hi, I am trying to integrate the Zoom SDK with simple pretty much join such the user should not enter the meeting ID or passcode to enter the meeting. Meeting ID and passcode i want from the database of XAMPP mysql (phpmyadmin) to fetch the meeting id and passcode by name.
The user should only see the join button and click and join the meeting and on the next tab. I am new to NodeJS so is there any way to run the SQL queries from nodeJS and fetch the data.Can we also create the function in nodeJS and call it from HTML file to access the NodeJS and run the SQL queries and set the data in html by id using ajax.

Please need help !!!

index.html (Page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

   <head>
   <title>Zoom WebSDK</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
    href="node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
href="node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/css/react-select.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/try.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" href="corp.js"></script>

   <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
   maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
   </head>

   <body>

<style>
    .sdk-select {
        height: 34px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    
    .websdktest button {
        float: right;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    #nav-tool {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

    #show-test-tool {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 0;
        display: block;
        z-index: 99999;        
    }
    #display_name {
        width: 250px;
    }
    

    #websdk-iframe {
        width: 700px;
        height: 500px;
        border: 1px;
        border-color: red;
        border-style: dashed;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        left: 50%;
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>

<nav id="nav-tool" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Zoom WebSDK</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="websdktest">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" id="meeting_form" action="meeting.html" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="display_name" id="display_name" value="1.9.8#Local" maxLength="100"
                        placeholder="Name" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="meeting_number" id="meeting_number" value="" maxLength="200"
                        style="width:150px" placeholder="Meeting Number" class="form-control" required> </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="meeting_pwd" id="meeting_pwd" value="" style="width:150px"
                        maxLength="32" placeholder="Meeting Password" class="form-control"> </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="meeting_email" id="meeting_email" value="" style="width:150px"
                        maxLength="32" placeholder="Email option" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select id="meeting_role" class="sdk-select">
                        <option value=0>Attendee</option>
                        <option value=1>Host</option>
                        <option value=5>Assistant</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                    <select id="meeting_china" class="sdk-select">
                        <option value=0>Global</option>
                        <option value=1>China</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select id="meeting_lang" class="sdk-select">
                        <option value="en-US">English</option>
                        <option value="de-DE">German Deutsch</option>
                        <option value="es-ES">Spanish Español</option>
                        <option value="fr-FR">French Français</option>
                        <option value="jp-JP">Japanese 日本語</option>
                        <option value="pt-PT">Portuguese Portuguese</option>
                        <option value="ru-RU">Russian Русский</option>
                        <option value="zh-CN">Chinese 简体中文</option>
                        <option value="zh-TW">Chinese 繁体中文</option>
                        <option value="ko-KO">Korean 한국어</option>
                        <option value="vi-VN">Vietnamese Tiếng Việt</option>
                        <option value="it-IT">Italian italiano</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <input type="hidden" value="" id="copy_link_value"/>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="join_meeting">Join</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="join" name="join">Join</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="clear_all">Clear</button>
                <button type="button" link="" onclick="window.copyJoinLink('#copy_join_link')" class="btn btn-primary" id="copy_join_link">Copy Direct join link</button>
       

            </form>
            <form action="/index" method="GET">
                <input type="text" id="text1">
                <input type="hidden" id="display_name_id">
                <input type="hidden" id="meeting_number_id">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>

<div id="show-test-tool">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="show-test-tool-btn" title="show or hide top test tool">Show</button>
</div>




<script>
    document.getElementById('show-test-tool-btn').addEventListener("click", function(e){
        var textContent = e.target.textContent;
        if (textContent === 'Show') {
            document.getElementById('nav-tool').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('show-test-tool-btn').textContent = 'Hide';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('nav-tool').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('show-test-tool-btn').textContent = 'Show';
        }
    })

      
</script>





<script>
    //const f = require('./corp');

    $('#join').click(function(){
        
        /*
        call();
        $('#display_name_id').val(sessionStorage.getItem('display_name'));
        console.log($('#display_name_id').val());
        var meeting_number = sessionStorage.getItem('meeting_number');
        console.log(meeting_number);
        console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('meeting_number'));
        */
        //AjaxController.callAjax();
    });
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/react/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/redux/dist/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/redux-thunk/dist/redux-thunk.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/lodash/lodash.min.js"></script>

<script src="./js/tool.js"></script>
<script src="./static/index.min.js"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

index.js

```
    import { ZoomMtg } from "@zoomus/websdk";



         //const mysql = require('mysql');

          console.log("checkSystemRequirements");
           
           
          console.log(JSON.stringify(ZoomMtg.checkSystemRequirements()));

         // it's option if you want to change the WebSDK dependency link 
          resources. setZoomJSLib must be run at first
          // if (!china) 
              ZoomMtg.setZoomJSLib('https://source.zoom.us/1.9.8/lib', ' 
               /av'); // CDN version default
               // else 
              ZoomMtg.setZoomJSLib('https://jssdk.zoomus.cn/1.9.8/lib', '/av'); // china cdn option
// 
 
 

    ZoomMtg.setZoomJSLib('http://localhost:9999/node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/lib', '/av'); // Local version default, Angular Project change 
           to use 
         cdn version
      ZoomMtg.preLoadWasm();
       ZoomMtg.prepareJssdk();

const API_KEY = "THE_API_KEY";
/**
 * NEVER PUT YOUR ACTUAL API SECRET IN CLIENT SIDE CODE, THIS IS JUST FOR QUICK PROTOTYPING
 * The below generateSignature should be done server side as not to expose your api secret in public
 * You can find an eaxmple in here: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/Web-Client-SDK/tutorial/generate-signature
 */
const API_SECRET = "THE_API_SECRET";

testTool = window.testTool;
document.getElementById("display_name").value =
  "Local" +
  ZoomMtg.getJSSDKVersion()[0] +
  testTool.detectOS() +
  "#" +
  testTool.getBrowserInfo();
document.getElementById("meeting_number").value = testTool.getCookie(
  "meeting_number"
);
document.getElementById("meeting_pwd").value = testTool.getCookie(
  "meeting_pwd"
);
if (testTool.getCookie("meeting_lang"))
  document.getElementById("meeting_lang").value = testTool.getCookie(
    "meeting_lang"
  );

document.getElementById("meeting_lang").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  /* testTool.setCookie(
    "meeting_lang",
    document.getElementById("meeting_lang").value
  ); */
  ZoomMtg.i18n.load(document.getElementById("meeting_lang").value);
  ZoomMtg.i18n.reload(document.getElementById("meeting_lang").value);
  ZoomMtg.reRender({ lang: document.getElementById("meeting_lang").value });
});

// copy zoom invite link to mn, autofill mn and pwd.
document
  .getElementById("meeting_number")
  .addEventListener("input", function (e) {
    let tmpMn = e.target.value.replace(/([^0-9])+/i, "");
    if (tmpMn.match(/([0-9]{9,11})/)) {
      tmpMn = tmpMn.match(/([0-9]{9,11})/)[1];
    }
    let tmpPwd = e.target.value.match(/pwd=([\d,\w]+)/);
    if (tmpPwd) {
     // document.getElementById("meeting_pwd").value = tmpPwd[1];
      //testTool.setCookie("meeting_pwd", tmpPwd[1]);
    }
    //document.getElementById("meeting_number").value = tmpMn;
    /*testTool.setCookie(
      "meeting_number",
      document.getElementById("meeting_number").value
    ); */
  });

document.getElementById("clear_all").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  testTool.deleteAllCookies();
  document.getElementById("display_name").value = "";
  document.getElementById("meeting_number").value = "";
  document.getElementById("meeting_pwd").value = "";
  document.getElementById("meeting_lang").value = "en-US";
  document.getElementById("meeting_role").value = 0;
  window.location.href = "/index.html";
});

document.getElementById("join_meeting").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const meetingConfig = testTool.getMeetingConfig();
  if (!meetingConfig.mn || !meetingConfig.name) {
    alert("Meeting number or username is empty");
    return false;
  }
  //testTool.setCookie("meeting_number", meetingConfig.mn);
  //testTool.setCookie("meeting_pwd", meetingConfig.pwd);

  const signature = ZoomMtg.generateSignature({
    meetingNumber: meetingConfig.mn,
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    apiSecret: API_SECRET,
    role: meetingConfig.role,
    success: function (res) {
      console.log(res.result);
      meetingConfig.signature = res.result;
      meetingConfig.apiKey = API_KEY;
      const joinUrl = "meeting.html?" + testTool.serialize(meetingConfig);
      const joinUrl1= "meeting.html";
      console.log(window.location.href+'/'+joinUrl);
      console.log(window.location.href);
      sessionStorage.setItem("url",joinUrl);
      //const url1="test.php";
      //window.open(url1,"_blank");
      window.open(joinUrl1, "_blank");
    },
  });
});


function copyToClipboard(elementId) {
  var aux = document.createElement("input");
  aux.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById(elementId).getAttribute('link'));
  document.body.appendChild(aux);  
  aux.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(aux);
}

// click copy jon link button
window.copyJoinLink = function (element) {
  const meetingConfig = testTool.getMeetingConfig();
  if (!meetingConfig.mn || !meetingConfig.name) {
    alert("Meeting number or username is empty");
    return false;
  }
  const signature = ZoomMtg.generateSignature({
    meetingNumber: meetingConfig.mn,
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    apiSecret: API_SECRET,
    role: meetingConfig.role,
    success: function (res) {
      console.log(res.result);
      meetingConfig.signature = res.result;
      meetingConfig.apiKey = API_KEY;
      const joinUrl =
        testTool.getCurrentDomain() +
        "/meeting.html?" +
        testTool.serialize(meetingConfig);
      document.getElementById('copy_link_value').setAttribute('link', joinUrl);
      copyToClipboard('copy_link_value');
    },
  });
};
```

meeting.js

```
    import { ZoomMtg } from "@zoomus/websdk";
const testTool = window.testTool;
// get meeting args from url
const tmpArgs = testTool.parseQuery();
const meetingConfig = {
  apiKey: tmpArgs.apiKey,
  meetingNumber: tmpArgs.mn,
  userName: (function () {
    if (tmpArgs.name) {
      try {
        return testTool.b64DecodeUnicode(tmpArgs.name);
      } catch (e) {
        return tmpArgs.name;
      }
    }
    return (
      "CDN#" +
      tmpArgs.version +
      "#" +
      testTool.detectOS() +
      "#" +
      testTool.getBrowserInfo()
    );
  })(),
  passWord: tmpArgs.pwd,
  leaveUrl: "/index.html",
  role: parseInt(tmpArgs.role, 10),
  userEmail: (function () {
    try {
      return testTool.b64DecodeUnicode(tmpArgs.email);
    } catch (e) {
      return tmpArgs.email;
    }
  })(),
  lang: tmpArgs.lang,
  signature: tmpArgs.signature || "",
  china: tmpArgs.china === "1",
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(ZoomMtg.checkSystemRequirements()));

// it's option if you want to change the WebSDK dependency link resources. setZoomJSLib must be run at first
ZoomMtg.preLoadWasm();
ZoomMtg.prepareJssdk();
function beginJoin(signature) {
  ZoomMtg.init({
    leaveUrl: meetingConfig.leaveUrl,
    disableCORP: !window.crossOriginIsolated, // default true
    // disablePreview: false, // default false
    success: function () {
      console.log(meetingConfig);
      console.log("signature", signature);
      ZoomMtg.i18n.load(meetingConfig.lang);
      ZoomMtg.i18n.reload(meetingConfig.lang);
      ZoomMtg.join({
        meetingNumber: meetingConfig.meetingNumber,
        userName: meetingConfig.userName,
        signature: signature,
        apiKey: meetingConfig.apiKey,
        userEmail: meetingConfig.userEmail,
        passWord: meetingConfig.passWord,
        success: function (res) {
          console.log("join meeting success");
          console.log("get attendeelist");
          ZoomMtg.getAttendeeslist({});
          ZoomMtg.getCurrentUser({
            success: function (res) {
              console.log("success getCurrentUser", res.result.currentUser);

            },
          });
        },
        error: function (res) {
          console.log(res);
        },
      });
    },
    error: function (res) {
      console.log(res);
    },
  });

  ZoomMtg.inMeetingServiceListener('onUserJoin', function (data) {
    console.log('inMeetingServiceListener onUserJoin', data);
  });

  ZoomMtg.inMeetingServiceListener('onUserLeave', function (data) {
    console.log('inMeetingServiceListener onUserLeave', data);
  });

  ZoomMtg.inMeetingServiceListener('onUserIsInWaitingRoom', function (data) {
    console.log('inMeetingServiceListener onUserIsInWaitingRoom', data);
  });

  ZoomMtg.inMeetingServiceListener('onMeetingStatus', function (data) {
    console.log('inMeetingServiceListener onMeetingStatus', data);
  });
  
}


beginJoin(meetingConfig.signature);
```

meeting.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Zoom WebSDK</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/@zoomus/websdk/dist/css/react-select.css" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="">
</head>

<body>
    <button class='btn btn-success'>Hello</button>
    <script src="node_modules/react/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/redux/dist/redux.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/redux-thunk/dist/redux-thunk.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/lodash/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tool.js"></script>
    <!--
    <script src="./static/meeting.min.js"></script>
    -->
    <script>
        const simd = async () => WebAssembly.validate(new Uint8Array([0, 97, 115, 109, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 1, 96, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 10, 9, 1, 7, 0, 65, 0, 253, 15, 26, 11]))
        simd().then((res) => {
          console.log("simd check", res);
        });
    </script>
    <script src="./static/index.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./static/meeting.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

webpack.config.dev.js

```
    const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const args = process.argv.slice(2);
let https = false;
let disableCORP = true;
if (args.includes('--https')) https = true;
if (args.includes('--corp')) disableCORP = false;
console.log('https', https);
console.log('disableCORP', disableCORP);
const mysql =  require('mysql');

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "zoom"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "zoom"
});




module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: {
    index: ['./js/index.js'],
    meeting: ['./js/meeting.js']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/static'),
    publicPath: '/static',
    hashDigestLength: 5,
    // filename: `zoom-meeting-${buildVersion}-[name]-[chunkhash].min.js`,
    filename: '[name].min.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 500000
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  externals: {
    'babel-polyfill': 'babel-polyfill',
    react: 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    redux: 'Redux',
    'redux-thunk': 'ReduxThunk',
    lodash: {
      commonjs: 'lodash',
      amd: 'lodash',
      root: '_',
      var: '_'
    }
  },
  context: __dirname,
  target: 'web',
  devServer: {
    https,
    cert: './localhost.crt',
    key: './localhost.key',
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 9999,
    hot: true,
    overlay: true,
    historyApiFallback: false,
    watchContentBase: true,
    disableHostCheck: true,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': https
        ? 'https://0.0.0.0:9999'
        : 'http://0.0.0.0:9999'
    },
    open: 'chrome',
    openPage: https ? 'https://127.0.0.1:9999' : 'http://127.0.0.1:9999'
  },
  mode: 'development',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
      'process.env.BABEL_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
    })
  ]
}
```

corp.js

```
    const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.dev');


function runFunc(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log('Listening at http://127.0.0.1:9999/index.html');
}




new WebpackDevServer(webpack(webpackConfig), {
  publicPath: '/static',
  hot: true,
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  open: 'chrome',
  after(app, server) {
  },
  headers: {
    // 'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy': 'unsafe-none',
    // 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy': 'unsafe-none',
  },
  openPage: 'http://127.0.0.1:9999/index.html',
  disableHostCheck: true,
  historyApiFallback: true,
  proxy: [{
    path: '/meeting.html',
    target: 'http://127.0.0.1:9998/'
  }]
}).listen(9999, '0.0.0.0', runFunc);

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(webpackConfig), {
  publicPath: '/static',
  hot: true,
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  after(app, server) {
  },
  headers: {
    'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy': 'require-corp',
    'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy': 'same-origin',
  },
  disableHostCheck: true,
  historyApiFallback: true,
}).listen(9998, '0.0.0.0', runFunc);
```

Comment: These kinds of questions can very easily be answered by just googling https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp

Comment: Thank you reply, but my problem is that i want to access the nodeJS file function from HTML page and run the SQL queries and set the data in session which is the result of query( meeting ID and passcode stored in the database) and create the zoom meeting link and join the meeting link in the next tab.

Comment: @DevWithZachary

Comment: Means run the mysql query by button click and start the meeting

Comment: So use javascript to make a request to the nodejs server and trigger the function.

Comment: I tried to use the JS to trigger but for some reason mysql of NodeJS does not seens to either be used by require() or import. @DevWithZachary

Comment: I want to use mysql of NodeJS like this

Comment: import { ZoomMtg } from "@zoomus/websdk";    from zoom SDK

Comment: If you have tried to do something show us the code, we are not here to just write code for you or help you research topics. This site is for specific programming questions

Comment: @DevWithZachary I have uploaded the  source code